# Implementaion of GSCoverageEncoder for WorldImage in Java

Tags: geoserver, rest

I want to upload a raster image to GeoServer as WorldImage from my Java application. I'm using [geoserver-manager v1.4.2](http://code.google.com/p/geoserver-manager) - a Java-based implementation of GeoServer's REST API. It provides convenient methods to work with the  GeoServer REST API.

The problem is that the support for the raster image types is not implemented (only Image Mosaic is [supported](http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/javadoc/gsman/apidocs/index.html) , which doesn't suite me).

Does anyone has an example implementation of GSCoverageEncoder for an image with world file?